# Android: not abe to find Looper.quit()

Tags: android, loops

The title explains it all. I have a class that extends AsyncTask. I call it directly in main thread using new classname.execute().

Now in the doInBackground(params) i have Looper.prepare.
Since i am getting an error "Only one Looper may be created per thread", i need to use Looper.quit() inside it. But i am not able to find it inside Looper class when i write Looper.quit();

So how to use this quit function

Comment: hmmm no one gave a solution to it....... here......, , and i can't find it

Comment: Can you post what you're doing in `doInBackground`?  It's not clear why you want to call `Looper.prepare()` in the background thread, and why you want to call it more than once.  I don't think calling `quit()` is the right answer for this issue though since it won't let you call `Looper.prepare()` again -- `Looper.prepare()` can only be called once per thread, even if quit is invoked.  That said, the answer to the question about `quit()` is that it's an instance method, so you'd have to do something like `Looper.myLopper().quit()`.

Comment: i don't have the code now, because this question is very old, but i also think that this is the reason, i implemented two asyncTasks....... may be this is the reason for it..........

Answer (score 4):

You have to invoke Looper.myLooper().quit()